# Is numpy.random.shuffle and random.shuffle interchangeable for lists?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, shuffle

I need to generate 100,000 random combinations from a list that contains over 92,000 values.  I achieve this by calling the code here 100,000 times.  I choose numpy random shuffle over random shuffle simply to keep from having another import statement.  I found documentation that leads me to think random.shuffle may only needs to be done once but I could not find an explanation for numpy.random.shuffle thus the 10 loops shuffling the list.  On a simple list like this is there a reason to use one shuffle over the other?

```
def sub_grouping(self):
    shuffle_count = 0
    while shuffle_count <= 10:
        np.random.shuffle(self.bin_tracking_list)
        shuffle_count += 1
    for n in itertools.combinations(self.bin_tracking_list, int(self.freq_group_size)):
        for chrom in self.chrom_seg_dict:
            w = np.intersect1d(n, self.chrom_seg_dict[chrom])
            if len(w) > 0:
                for seg in w:
                    self.tmp_seg_freq_dict[chrom][seg] += 1
        return self
```

Comment: *"... thus the 10 loops shuffling the list"*  I'm sorry, but I don't understand this comment.  Why are you shuffling 10 times?  One call to shuffle will give a (pseudo-)random permutation.  Shuffling again gives you a different permutation, but it is not any "more" random.

Comment: That would appear to be my misunderstanding of the shuffle.  The docs stated that long lists would exceed the permutations.  I was thinking of the list as a deck of cards and wanted to make sure they were as random as possible.

Comment: OK, the documentation for the standard library function `random.shuffle` says "Note that for even rather small len(x), the total number of permutations of x is larger than the period of most random number generators; this implies that most permutations of a long sequence can never be generated."  Calling shuffle multiple times won't help with that.